# CSS strange behavior: overflow and margin-left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a nice transition for my site's menu: when the user hovers over the parent item, the children slide down and when the mouse leaves, they should go back up. But they don't, as seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83aho201/2/). Then I asked for help here on SO and was pointed to using the `overflow: hidden;` approach and only transition the `height`. Okay. But that hid my child item's children items as seen in the snippet below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: 180px;
}

#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

#menu ul li {
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.2s ease 0s;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#menu ul li:hover>ul>li {
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Parent Item
      <ul>
        <li>Child Item</li>
        <li>Child Item &gt;
          <ul>
            <li>Child Child Item 1</li>
            <li>Child Child Item 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

So basically the "Child Child Item 1" and "Child Child Item 2" items are invisible to the user. How can I have both the slide down/up transition on mouse hover/leave and display both child items? Can it be done in pure CSS?

Comment: I notice that I had given an answer to your original question. If you find the solution below acceptable I can update the answer in your original question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an initial `opacity` on the `li` to 0, in addition to a `height` of 0.

On `:hover`, change the `opacity` to 1. Note that I haven't included opacity in the `transition` effect. I think it may look better for it to change immediately.

**updated**

Instead of using `opacity`, I think setting the initial `font-size` to 0 and scaling up will produce a smoother effect. I've added classes to the triggers and menus for clarity.

```css
* {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: 180px;
}

#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

#menu ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-one li,
.dropdown-two li {
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: height 0.2s ease 0s;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.dropdown-trigger-one:hover .dropdown-one>li,
.dropdown-trigger-two:hover .dropdown-two>li {
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown-trigger-one">Parent Item
      <ul class="dropdown-one">
        <li>Child Item</li>
        <li class="dropdown-trigger-two">Child Item &gt;
          <ul class="dropdown-two">
            <li>Child Child Item 1</li>
            <li>Child Child Item 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```